# Javascript—I can `console.log(value)` but `var x = value` throws an 'undefined' error

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I am using bluebird promises to return info from a database. The code below retrieves all contacts from my database and then runs a function to determine the response data it should send.

```
app.get("/contact", function(req, res) {
    database.get("contacts").then(function(contacts) {
        console.log(contacts[0].id);
        var group = contacts[0].id;
        .....
```

When this code runs, it successfully logs the id of the 0th user to the console, but it fails on the very next line with `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

I don't understand what is causing this error—to my knowledge, the scope hasn't changed at all between the two lines, and they are literally one after the other. What is the source of the problem?

Comment: probably a loop, so there are entries that don't have an id. Use if to wrap `if (contacts[0]){...}`. I imagine some contacts could return `null`.

Comment: try to console.log(contacts) , console.log(contacts.length) console.log(contacts[0]) and see the up coming result

Comment: @Mouser, the if wrap worked but I have no idea why—is it bluebird that is doing the looping under the hood?

Comment: Well since contacts is an array containing all the returned contacts it think that they are looped. However I don't know what happens in the `then` functions.. The console should give more information.

Comment: @FarzamBabar I tried your suggestiong and got some weird output when I ran my tests:

`[ { id: 1, name: 'Joe Smith' } ]`
`1`
`{ id: 1, name: 'Joe Smith' }`
`      should return 1 contact with its users`
`[]`
`0`
`undefined`.
I only had three `console.log()` statements, so it looks like part of the function is being run elsewhere in my suite. I guess that's what explains the error @Mouser.

Comment: @adc17 No, Bluebird does nothing with your array under the hood. You might want to show us how `database.get` is implemented.

Comment: Also, maybe there's no loop but you're just hitting the `/contact` route twice?

Comment: Yep, exactly @Bergi

Comment: @Mouser you were first if you want to claim the points.